# PowerPC ELF32 detecting VLE

Tags: powerpc

I am writing an ELF32 parser and disassembler for PowerPC.

Does anyone knows how to detect if the file is using VLE architecture from ELF header? I see that IDA can do it automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the code of `readelf` in the GNU binutils package, the presence of VLE instructions can be found in the `p_flags` and `sh_flags` fields with the mask `0x10000000` (see `binutils-xxx/include/elf/ppc.h` and look for `PF_PPC_VLE` and `SHF_PPC_VLE`).

These flags seems to be present at the begining of each section in the ELF format. So, you should look for it.

A few interesting readings:

- [Power Architecture® 32-bit Application Binary Interface Supplement 1.0](https://www.polyomino.org.uk/publications/2011/Power-Arch-32-bit-ABI-supp-1.0-Unified.pdf).
- [Variable-Length Encoding (VLE) extension programming interface manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/ac/f2/bf/01/73/d8/48/e0/CD00161395.pdf/files/CD00161395.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00161395.pdf).
- [Variable-Length Encoding (VLE) Extension Programming Interface Manual](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/supporting-information/VLEPIM.pdf).
- [64-bit PowerPC ELF Application Binary Interface Supplement 1.9](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/ELF/ppc64/PPC-elf64abi.html).
- The binutils source code (`grep -r _PPC_VLE`).